# Running a cross-index search similar to mongo $lookup in elasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two indexes index1 and index2. Index2 docs have an id of documents from index1. I want to fetch all documents of index1 and the result set of each doc should have an ArrayField of all the documents in index2 that have a matching id of index1 docs. Much similar to how LOOKUP works in mongo aggregation. I am new to ELS. Is there a way to achieve something similar in ELS? As an example, I am adding sample docs for both indexes and the result set I would prefer.

```
const index_documents = {
    "index1": [{
            doc_id: "A1",
            name: "nameID1"
        },
        {
            doc_id: "A2",
            name: "nameID2"
        },
        {
            doc_id: "A3",
            name: "nameID3"
        }
    ],
    "index2": [
        {
            doc_id: "B1",
            index1_id: "A1",
            class: "className1"
        },
        {
            doc_id: "B2",
            index1_id: "A2",
            class: "className2"
        },
        {
            doc_id: "B3",
            index1_id: "A1",
            class: "className3"
        },
        {
            doc_id: "B4",
            index1_id: "A4",
            class: "className3"
        },
    ]
}

expected_ResultSet = [
    {
        doc_id: "A1",
        name: "nameID1",
        index2_docs = [    
            {
                doc_id: "B1",
                index1_id: "A1",
                class: "className1"
            },
            {
                doc_id: "B3",
                index1_id: "A1",
                class: "className3"
            },
        ],
        total_index2_count:2
    },
    {
        doc_id: "A2",
        name: "nameID2",
        index2_docs:[
            {
                doc_id: "B2",
                index1_id: "A2",
                class: "className2"
            }
        ],
        total_index2_count:1
    },
    {
        doc_id: "A3",
        name: "nameID3",
        index2_docs:[],
        total_index2_count:0
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

there's no way to do this type of join in Elasticsearch sorry to say

your best bet is to merge both documents into one

Comment: Thanks.I knew it but still wanted to confirm